QtIFW on Windows: how to invoke uninstaller if user tries to uninstall app
On Windows, if you right-click > Uninstall an app, by default it opens the Settings app on Apps > Installed Apps. However for many apps, it will start a custom uninstaller instead.
For an app installed using the Qt Installer Framework (QtIFW) you also get an installer (e.g. MaintenanceTool.exe). This can be executed in uninstaller mode using the --start-uninstaller command line option.
How do I link the two?
In other words, if a user tries to directly uninstall my app, I want it to invoke C:\Program Files\MyApp\MaintenanceTool.exe --start-uninstaller.

Add your registry info here.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MaintenanceTool (The name is optional.)
You'll need to provide:
UninstallString (Your command for uninstallation, if I'm correct.)
InstallLocation (The folder or directory where the person installed their app.)
I don't really have a lot of experience on this kind of thing, so I assume this is the correct answer based on my knowledge.
